# Tkinter : Getting screen text unit width. (Not pixels)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter to design a UI for an application. I'm using grid geometry and while specifying button width (or any widget width), I realized that width should be specified in text units and not pixels. Since I want to make it platform independent and screen size independent Is there any method to get max text unit width ? So that I can do math on basis of that.

For example:

I've 10 buttons in a row, which should be of equal width. If I hard code a width value specific to current screen value, it would not work on diff screen wise.

Thanks.

Comment: And what do you mean width should be specified in characters not pixels? width for button can be specified as - `tk.Button(mWindow, height=5, width=20, text="Main Menu", command=mmWindow)`

Comment: are you aware there are options for the grid geometry manager to make all of the columns in a row a uniform width? Also, are you aware that if you make each button the same width (in character widths), they will in fact be exactly the same size?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to make a GUI that is "platform independent and screen size independent", you definitely *do not* want to be measuring sizes yourself. Unless, by saying you want something platform independent, you're saying you want a button to be X pixels regardless of pixel density or screen resolution (which seems like a very bad idea).

The whole reason tkinter supports measuring in character units, along with options for widgets to stretch and shrink, is to support platform independence. When you start working at the pixel level, you will have many, many problems when you run the code on other platforms, or on other displays, or with other fonts.

That being said, the `measure` method of a font can tell you exactly how many pixels a given string will require in a given font. If you want to know how wide "one character" is, you can use the `measure` method on the string `"0"`, which is what tkinter uses as a base when computing widths based on characters.

If you want buttons to be exactly the same size, using character widths will give you that, because it isn't the width of 10 actual characters in that widget, but ten average character widths. In that case, "10 characters" will be the same for every widget, no matter what the contents of that widget.

Comment: And is there a way to measure it the other way around? So to get how many characters you can fit into a given ammount of pixels in width for a specific font?

Comment: @Nummer_42O: yes. Tkinter has functions that can calculate in pixels the length of a string in a given font.

Comment: And what function is that? ^^'

Answer (score 13):

Using the `tkinter.font` package you can create Tk font objects to define a font and call the `measure` method to obtain the screen width of text using that font.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkfont
root = tk.Tk()
font = tkfont.Font(family="Consolas", size=10, weight="normal")
m_len = font.measure("m")
```

For monospace fonts, any character will do. For proportional text, if you give the whole string you get the screen length of the string. Otherwise you typically get the size of *m* or *n* as either a maximum or an average character width.

However, buttons are typically all the same size on many UI styles. Varying the button sizes is likely to look quite poor. You can specify a negative width to set a [minimum](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_widget.htm#M-width) width for the widget which can be helpful.

Comment: Why do you say a negative size is in "dialog units"? According to the tcl/tk man page, an negative size denotes a minimum (either in pixels or characters, depending on what is in the button)

Comment: Ah - I've mis-remembered what negative widths are doing. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

You must be having a root variable like-

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
```

You can use `root.winfo_sccreenwidth()` for width

```
width = root.winfo_screenwidth() #width of screen
height = root.winfo_screenheight() # height of screen
```

I am not sure about any way to get the screenwidth in text units, it may not even be possible.

A solution would be to be able to specify the button width in pixels, you can do this by following a simple example given [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578887-text-widget-width-and-height-in-pixels-tkinter/).

What you do is - put the Button widget inside a frame and specify the height and width for the frame , and then make frame not propagate the size using `grid_propagate(False)` for the frame and then making the button expand upto the frame (maybe by using grid `sticky="we"` )

Comment: Agreed but that gives me information in pixels not in character size, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by character size? Do you mean number of text units?

Comment: I mean in text units. For example, if I set width of my tk button to 12. It means it can accommodate 12 text characters in it.

Comment: @dastaan what if you're not using a monospace font?

Comment: @AdamSmith That's a valid point. But let's assume that I'm using a monospace font.

Comment: The width of one character is based on an average width. More accurately, it's the width of the zero ("0") character IIRC. If you are using a variable-width font, a width of "10" will accommodate 10 zeros, a few more "i"s, or slightly fewer "w"s.